# Should the maximum element of a van Emde Boas Tree be stored outside the tree?

Tags: data-structures, van-emde-boas-trees

Don't we need to treat the max element similarly to the min element? Why we can have this asymmetry and still perform operations in 0(loglogN) time? The max element propagate down the tree but the min does not... Is it possible with the reversed case to have the time for operations?

I found here: http://code.google.com/p/libveb/wiki/Intro  that we need to store it because the sqrt of element is time consuming operation. But I think that there is something else.

Answer (score 4):

I think what the op is asking is why are we not storing the max element similar to the min element i.e. why do we propagate the max element down into the tree and whether this treatment cant be reversed.

We store the min element outside the tree since its presence suggests that that particular structure is non-empty which prevents us from making an unnecessary recursive call to check for emptiness and makes insertion into an empty tree an O(1) operation i.e just set the minimum element. We need both max and min elements outside the tree for the successor and predecessor operations.

This is explained rather nicely in Erik Demaine's lecture notes (link provided by templatetypedef).

I believe it should be possible to keep either of the min/max elements outside without propagation and still maintain O(log log u) time per operation since we do this just to know if a structure is non-empty. Keeping both of them and not propagating both of them down is redundant and won't buy you extra time.

Answer (score 1):

van Emde Boas trees do typically store the maximum and minimum values separately, since otherwise you cannot efficiently implement successor and predecessor.

Is there a specific source you've seen that suggests otherwise?  All of the notes on vEB-trees that I have seen describe storing both the maximum and minimum values this way.  See

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree),
- [Erik Demaine's lecture notes](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.897/spring03/scribe_notes/L1/lecture1.pdf)
- [These other lecture notes](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~gudmund/dynamicF04/vEB.pdf)

Hope this helps!